# CSS for rows of logos

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to code a row of logos in the footer of website https://www.andromedi.com/

The desktop version works fine but the mobile needs to looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pT4C4.png)

I checked online and the way to go apparently is using flexbox (I still need to better understand the difference between css-grid and flexbox)

The css code:

```css
.footer-asociaciones-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1.5rem 5rem;
}


.footer-asociaciones-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer-asociaciones-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

.footer-asociaciones-column img {
    height:100px;
}

.footer-asociaciones-column a {
    margin: auto;
}

p.footer-asociaciones-title {
  padding: 1.5rem 1rem;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'DIN1451EngschriftRegular';
  font-size: large;
}
```

I tried using width: 33%; but then [the logos overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl5xt.png)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: are you looking for nowrap option of the flexbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to @BugsArePeopleToo I came up with the solution:

```css
.footer-asociaciones-column {
    display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 33%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 481px) {

    .footer-asociaciones-column {
        flex-basis: 100%;
        flex: 1;
    }

}

.footer-asociaciones-column img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to give your images `max-width` and `max-height` dimensions so they change according to the size of their containers. Auto values for `height` and `width` are there to maintain aspect ratio of the images.

```
.footer-asociaciones-column img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The result was this one https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfRfR.png so not what I'm looking for. It did help me though to get to the solution. Thanks!